# iOS JSON Parsing error

Tags: ios, json, parsing

I am trying to parse a json here but keep on getting errors for some reason. my code is

```
    NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://api.wunderground.com/api/3c158b3b3cd6ce90/hourly/q/11758.json"];//, query];
NSString *string2 = [string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@"_"];
NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:
                [NSURL URLWithString:string]];
NSError* error;

NSDictionary *res = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:&error];

NSArray* latestLoans = [res objectForKey:@"forecast"]; //2
NSArray *tmp = [latestLoans valueForKey:@"temp"];
NSLog(@"temp: %@", tmp);
```

and the error is

```
temp: (null)
Entity: line 2: parser error : Start tag expected, '<' not found
{
^
```

I don't get this because the URL is real and gets a response, and I need help with this

Comment: What is the point of `string2`? It looks like it isn't used.

Comment: it was but for right now i'm just not using it

Comment: I don't see a key "forecast" in the response but there is "hourly_forecast".  That said, I don't see any reason that would cause the error you are getting - is that coming from later code?

Comment: yea that was the problem i did that because in the xml version there was a forecast key. thanks

Comment: Looks like some xml parsing error. Are you parsing some xml using xml parsers?

Comment: no i fixed it it was just because i had the key as "forecast" instead of "hourly_forecast"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for, "forecast", does not exist in the response. Perhaps what you are looking for is "hourly_forecast".

```
NSArray* latestLoans = [res objectForKey:@"hourly_forecast"]; //2
NSArray *tmp = [latestLoans valueForKey:@"temp"];
```